# Neo4J Create Node decimal

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is my query for Neo4J.

```
CREATE (angkorWat:Place:2015:Temple:Cambodia {name: “Angkor Wat”, lat: 13.4125, long: -103.866667);
```

However, I get

```
Invalid input '2': expected whitespace or a label name (line 1, column 25 (offset: 24))
```

I don't understand. I've gone through the docs and it seems like a valid query to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the use of the label "2015" needs to be escaped with backticks to avoid a Cypher identifier conflict:

```
CREATE (angkorWat:Place:`2015`:Temple:Cambodia {name: 'Angkor Wat', lat: 13.4125, long: -103.866667});
```

(Also, you query above is missing a closing curly brace)